# pointcloud_to_laserscan parameter min_height

Tags: ros, kinect, pointcloud-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hey guys,

short question:

Is the pointcloud_to_laserscan package capable of using negative values as min_height?

Background information:
I'm desperatly trying to get a scan out of my PointCloud2 data, that my kinect generates - as it happens the kinect is not on the ground level, which means that some obstacles have negative height values...
that somehow seems to be a problem for the node - the obstacles are part of the pcl, but the laserscan does not see them...
I hope you get what my problem is, for sure I can't be the first to try this :(

Edit:
Update
As a workaround I've changed some part of the cloud_to_scan.cpp file and
manually increased the height - this works, even though I don't understand why
-y+1 < min_height with min_height =0
works, wenn
-y < min_height with a value of -1 fails...

I mean, if y is like 0.5 in the first case it is:
-0.5+1 <0 => 0.5 < 0 => false
in the second case:
-0.5 < -1 => false

Edit:

Thanks for your answer, that indicates that somehow I messed up my package.
I'm sure that I set the parameters correct in the launchfile, and just to check that I changed the default values - with no result.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45362/pointcloud_to_laserscan-parameter-min_height/) by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 342 on 2012-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, the `min_height` parameter can be negative (anything between -10.0 and 10.0 meters). The only thing to look out for is that `pointcloud_to_laserscan` assumes the input PointCloud to be in the Kinect optical frame (x to the right, y down, z forward), while most other coordinate systems in ROS have x forward, y to the left, z up. That means that -y is up in `pointcloud_to_laserscan`.

BTW, you can use the following command to adjust these parameters dynamically with a GUI; that makes parameter tuning much easier:

```
rosrun dynamic_reconfigure reconfigure_gui
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on 2012-10-10**:
hmm, I'm pretty sure my launchfile works and sets the parameters right(tried some few extrema, which led to the results I expected)...still negative values won't work :(